# Rewrite a sub doman with sitemap.xml file in url to folder with sitemap.xml file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Which rewriterule I should  write?I have a lot of sitemap.xml files placed in folders separately one by one

The structure looks like this:

```
/sitemaps/moscow/sitemap.xml
/sitemaps/warsaw/sitemap.xml
/sitemaps/paris/sitemap.xml
```

and so on...

I would like to get them by going on next urls:

```
moscow.mydomain.com/sitemap.xml
warsaw.mydomain.com/sitemap.xml
paris.mydomain.com/sitemap.xml
```

...

So I need a redirect from `http://moscow.mydomain.com/sitemap.xml` to `http://moscow.mydomain.com/sitemap.xml`

Which rewriterule I should write in .htaccess file?

**UPDATE**

Thanks, but I found out a right solution, here it is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemaps/%1/sitemap.xml [L]
```

Works strictly as I wanted to!

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemaps/([^/]+)/(sitemap\.xml)$ http://$1.mydomain.com/$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```